# Example of a secondary representation of a module that is not a direct sum

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring. An $A$-module $M$ is said to be
> *secondary* if $M\neq 0$ and for each $a\in A $, the endomorphism
> $\phi_a:M\to M$ defined by $\phi_a(m)=am$ for $m\in M$ is either
> surjective or nilpotent.
> A *secondary representation* of an $A$-module $M$ is an expression of $M$ as a finite sum of  secondary submodules:
> $$M=N_1+\dotsb +  N_n.$$
> The representation is *minimal* if (1) the prime ideals $P_i: = \sqrt{(\operatorname{ann} N_i)}$ are all
> distinct, and (2) none of the $N_i$ is redundant.
> If a module $M$ has a secondary representation, then $M$ is called *representable*.

The above definitions come from P42–43 in [Commutative Ring Theory by Matsumura](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139171762).

Over a PID, any minimal secondary representation is a direct sum. What is an example of a secondary representation that is not a direct sum?